# How to view all decimal places in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read in some currency data from an excel sheet which has values with 10 decimal places, but when i read it in within the df it is dropping all the values to 2 decimal places which i dont want. Any help on how to get all the decimal places back would be great.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd as xlrd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.read_excel('Currency Data.xls','PPU')
df.head()
```

Comment: This is probably just pandas truncating on display for readability. Try changing the default display format with `pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.10f}".format` to see more places on display.

Comment: Thanks. that's sorted it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the Decimal library for python

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html